# Retrieving selected rows from jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid 3.5 (full) mostly working.  I have it retrieving data with the multi-select option on.  The one part I can not get to work is getting the selected rows.  The [docs](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fb79d.htm) state:

> To obtain selected rows we can use getGridParam('selarrrow') method. Using our example we can write this:
>
> jQuery("#grid_id").getGridParam('selarrrow');
>
> which will return an array with the selected rows (i.e., ["11","9"] from the figure above). The values in array are the id's of the selected rows.

This does not work and returns an undefined value (yes I have rows selected).  I also have xmlreader:id setup in my grid config.

Can someone point me to a direction to look?  I have tried everything I can think of to no avail.

**UPDATE:** redsquare was correct about incorrect selectors.  my containing div had the same ID as the grid, I noticed this when I went to check my setup code and the selector was `table#results` changed that and it all works.  Thanks all.  If you post an answer redsquare I will accept it as it is the correct answer.

Comment: can you upload your page? Are you sure the selectors are correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you check the selectors for me first. if they are correct can you try to upload your page or replicate the issue at jsbin.com. :)

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  I had a div with the same ID as my grid.

Answer (score 18):

Try this, It will return an array of selected rows' id.

```
var s;
s = jQuery("#yourGridName").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
alert(s);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using the `selrow` option which only returned one of the selected rows, but using `selarrrow` gives me them all.

Answer (score 4):

```
var rowKey = jQuery("#yourGridName").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
var rowObject = jQuery('#yourGridName').getRowData(rowKey);
```

This will also give the row details and using normal . operator you can get column value.

Answer (score 3):

You have to refer not to jQuery object, but to jqGrid itseft.

So, during initialization of grid, you write the code like:

```
var myGrid = $("#list")..jqGrid(....);
```

And in your event handler, if you want to retrieve the IDs of the selected rows, you have to write:

```
var rows = myGrid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the selected rows: `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');`

Comment: jQuery('#grid').getGridParam('selarrrow') is prettier