# I need to get the entire row data from jqGrid when i click the link in same row using jQgrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid-php

I am new to JQgrid and am unsure how to handle this use case.

When a user clicks on a link in a specific row in jQgrid I need to get the row data with a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for the above question is ,when your are clicking on the rows you will have a unique value for each rows from that we need to get the id and by using the jQgrid function.

With `getRowData` we can get that row column values.

The sample example is pasted below:

```
var reqlaborId = jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('getRowData', id);
reqlaborId = reqlaborId.ahcc_laborcan_header_id;
```

This works fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

[Retrieving original row data from jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788360/retrieving-original-row-data-from-jqgrid)

OR

[Retrieving selected rows from jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308873/retrieving-selected-rows-from-jqgrid)

Or else..

What I had done earlier was simpler.. appended the required data in link in a column as queryString.. e.g index.php?id=123   if it can work for u..

Answer (score 1):

```
var newKey=jQuery("input[name='key']").val();
```

where 'key' is name of column